# How could i make so php could load proxies from a txt file and then "rotate" them while using curlopt_proxy

Tags: php, file, curl, proxy

This is some of what i tried..
I still get an error *Call to a member function getProxy()* and *Undefined variable: rotate*, after i defined the getproxy function , i think im blind cuz there's something i cant see, please if you have some advice, share it :). PS: What i mean by rotate is by randomizing each proxy and use it when using curl "post" 
i'm sorry if this is a bad post.

````
Class RotateProxy{
    private $proxy = '';
    private $fp = '';
    private $list = array();
    private $counter; //number of times proxy used. Default is 1
    private $current; //number of times proxy HAS been used.

    public function __constructor($path,$counter=1){
        $this->list = trim(file($path));
        $this->$counter = $counter;
    }

    public function getProxy(){
        if($this->current > $this->counter){
            array_shift($this->list);

            $this->current = 1;

            $this->proxy = $this->list[0];

            return $this->proxy;
        }else{
            $this->current++;
            return $this->proxy;
        }
    }
}

$proxylist = __DIR__ . 'proxies.txt'; // just an example.
$proxy = $rotate->getProxy();
$counter = 1; // proxy will be used 5 times before moving to the next proxy.
$rotate = new RotateProxy($proxylist,$counter);
$session = mt_rand();
$curl = curl_init('https://api.ipify.org/');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);



if ($result)
    echo $result;
?>```
````

Comment: Invalid syntax `$this->$counter = $counter;`

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the instance of the RotateProxy class before you call methods on the instance. i.e. this way around:

```
$rotate = new RotateProxy($proxylist,$counter);
$proxy = $rotate->getProxy();
```

Comment: thanks yeah i just noticed that now, but still i cant get the proxies loaded for some reason..

Comment: How do you know that? Do you realize that you are always grabbing the first proxy with `$this->list[0]` ?